# Redis List "Unfinity"

Tags: node.js, list, redis

I'm monitoring a list of 100 elements using the Redis RPUSH LPOP commands. The first element of my list is the first value I provided, and the last element is the last value I provided. I always add elements using RPUSH, so the newest element is always at the end. I check the length using LLEN. If it's more than 100, I remove the first element using LPOP. This way, I always have the latest 100 numbers in my list. This mechanism works well and accomplishes what I need in an instant. However, I've encountered an issue where some list elements take on the value "Unifinity." I don't want this to happen, but I haven't been able to identify the circumstances under which this value occurs. Since my calculations are based on numbers, "Unifinity" disrupts my work.

I'm using Redis 3.0.504 Windows build, and I'm performing these operations in Node.js version 12.

Let me know if you need any further assistance or clarification!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve the error I encountered. I realized that the mistake I made was not related to Redis.

In my Node.js code, I was maintaining a buffer array and every 30 seconds I was transferring this array to Redis and emptying the buffer. When reading from the buffer, I found that undefined value was being transferred to Redis when the buffer was empty.

I rearranged the code so that when I empty the buffer, the last value becomes the first value. This way, I structured the buffer to always contain at least one element. As a result of this modification, I managed to overcome this error.